# mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on ''127.0.0.1':3306' (11001 getaddrinfo failed)

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I'm following a tutorial to learn to use mysql while using python and flask, in the tutorial we implemented some  modules and set a connection, we set some variables as well using the terminal and at the moment I try to use a command we set using some modules it throws me that error in the terminal.

**This is my init file**

```
from flask import Flask

def create_app(): # nos ayudara a crear varias instancias de nuestrsa aplicacion
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_mapping(
        SECRET_KEY = 'mikey', #esta llave se enviara al cliente para usarla como referencia con datos que se encuentran guardados en el servidor y es conocido como cookie
        DATABASE_HOST = os.environ.get('FLASK_DATABASE_HOST'),
        DATABASE_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('FLASK_DATABASE_PASSWORD'),
        DATABASE_USER = os.environ.get('FLASK_DATABASE_USER'),
        DATABASE = os.environ.get('FLASK_DATABASE')
    )

    from . import db

    db.init_app(app)
    
    @app.route('/')
    def test():
        return 'Hello Friend'
    
    return app
```

**This is my db config**

```
import mysql.connector
import click
from flask import current_app, g
from flask.cli import with_appcontext
from .schema import instructions

def get_db():
    if 'db' not in g:
        g.db = mysql.connector.connect(
            host = current_app.config['DATABASE_HOST'],
            user = current_app.config['DATABASE_USER'],
            password = current_app.config['DATABASE_PASSWORD'],
            database = current_app.config['DATABASE']
        )
        g.c = g.db.cursor(dictionary=True)
    return g.db, g.c

def close_db(e=None):
    db = g.pop('db', None)

    if db is not None:
        db.close()

def init_db():
    db, c = get_db()

    for i in instructions:
        c.execute(1)

    db.commit()

@click.command('init-db')
@with_appcontext
def init_db_command():
    init_db()
    click.echo('Base de datos inicializada')

def init_app(app):
    app.teardown_appcontext(close_db)
    app.cli.add_command(init_db_command)
```

**And these are the varibles**

```
set FLASK_DATABASE_HOST='localhost'
set FLASK_DATABASE_USER='nword'
set FLASK_DATABASE_PASSWORD='%2.-[NX^X?FpncFD'
set FLASK_DATABASE='flask_database'
```

[And this is my structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40DNN.png)

Comment: Use set without ‘